# awsAccessKeyID value is null error when running Powershell Provisionner on a Packer AMI with any AWS api

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, packer

I get the error "awsAccessKey value is null" when trying to access S3 or SSM from an AMI provisioned by Packer.  I am using an inline Powershell provisionner.  The inline code calls a ps1 file in which I attempt to download from S3 or access SSM.  The IAM role on the EC2 has correct permissions.

```
    {
      "type"              : "Powershell",
      "inline"           :[
         "c:\\temp\\runPs.ps1"
      ]
    }
```

runPs.ps1:
$value = (Get-SSMParameterValue -Name $SSMpath).Parameters[0].Value;

Tried to run a Shell provisionner that runs an S3 download to AMI instance and got this error: fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

```
    {
      "type"              : "windows-shell",
      "inline"           :[
         "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder/file.txt C:/Temp/file.txt"
      ]
    }
```

I am assuming the PS will assume the IAM role on the EC2 itself as specified in the builder.

--- More testing

I added an "assume_role" param to the builder as below: "assume_role" : {"role_arn" : "arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/{{user aws_iam_instance_profile}}"}.

I still get the same error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: awsAccessKeyId, System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. –

Comment: " The inline code calls" - which code? You haven't shown any code?

Comment: How are you providing the AWS credentials to Packer? Is it e.g. environment, template arguments, etc.?

Comment: I am assuming the PS will assume the IAM role on the  EC2 itself as specified in the builder         "builders": [{
        "type"                          : "amazon-ebs",
        "profile"                       : "{{user `aws_packer_profile`}}",
        "iam_instance_profile",  "iam_instance_profile"          : "{{user `aws_iam_instance_profile`}}",  Do I need to set the assume_role as well

Comment: More info, I added an "assume_role" param to the builder as below:           "assume_role"  : {"role_arn" : "arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/{{user `aws_iam_instance_profile`}}"}. Still got the same error      
 System.InvalidOperationException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: awsAccessKeyId, System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.